# Delete temporary canvas object in QGIS, e.g. lines drawn by the Profile Tool

Tags: qgis, profile

I'm using the [Profile Tool](https://anitagraser.com/2013/12/27/profile-tool-tutorial/) plugin (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/profiletool/) over a valid GeoTIFF raster DEM in QGIS 3.26.2-Buenos Aires on Ubuntu 22.04.1.

When you draw a line using the "Temporary polyline" solution, sometime, somehow, the red drawn line randomly stays on screen whatever you do:

[image]
*Here you can see the start of the drawing of a second line under the top one, which was drawn before, and decided to stay on the screen for no particular reason. Such line can pile up together and cannot be removed.*

And as it's a temporary object (it doesn't even appear in the table of content as such!) I cannot select it.
Hence, I cannot remove it as well.

How could I remove this/these drawn object(s)?

Comment: Try closing the `Profile tool` view window and check if that can remove the line. Also, click the `Refresh` button on QGIS main toolbar, or the `F5` button to refresh the view.

Comment: This is probably a problem with the plugin. I recommend that you create the issue in the bug tracker: https://github.com/PANOimagen/profiletool/issues.

Answer (score 1):

As Comrade Che mentioned in their comment, it is likely a problem with the plugin. However, until it is fixed you can try these functions in the Python console. They will indiscriminately remove all [QgsHighlight](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/gui/QgsHighlight.html) / [QgsRubberband](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/gui/QgsRubberBand.html) items though, so be careful if you have any other meaningful items of these types in your map canvas.

```py
def clear_highlights():
    """ Removes highlight objects from the map canvas """
    for item in iface.mapCanvas().scene().items():
        if isinstance(item, QgsHighlight):
            iface.mapCanvas().scene().removeItem(item)

def clear_rubberbands():
    """ Removes rubberband objects from the map canvas """
    for item in iface.mapCanvas().scene().items():
        if isinstance(item, QgsRubberBand):
            iface.mapCanvas().scene().removeItem(item) 


clear_highlights()
clear_rubberbands()
```